# Can a disk migration reset some system or app settings in Windows 11?

Tags: microsoft-word, ssd, migration, windows-11-v22h2

To speed up my migration to the new laptop, I have chosen the "brute-force mode":

1. Take my SSD M.2 out of old laptop and replace it with the original one in the new laptop.
2. Connect the new laptop to the Internet, start the Windows 11 and setup a new PIN there.
3. Restart Windows a couple of times to let it "resolve the hangover" and install all the drivers.

After that everything went as smudge as possible... except for settings.

I couple of days after the above I have realized that "something" has changes a number of my settings across the system and all my installed applications.

For example, this is my "old computer" configuration of the corresponding Word 365 config:

[image]

But the first time I started Word after "disk migration" I have found this:

[image]

And this:

[image]

Is this a kind of coincidence and both thing has nothing in common? And in this case the question should be:

> When Word 365 can decide that *Text Predictions* that I completely don't want to use are so cool that it will enable this feature again against my decision to turn it off in first place?

Or is it truly possible and the question should rather be:

> Can Windows 11 truly decide to change / reset some settings during disk migration + "hangover resolution" + driver installation?

(an example with Word, not some system settings, is given because I see no connection between the depicted settings and disk migration process).

Comment: See http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/13675-word-2007-later-key-data-file-locations.html. I am a amazed that this worked as well as it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Office 365 update can change settings and this can be influenced by
the computer's hardware.

In your case, I would think that Office detected this new computer
as a new installation, so took some actions that it considers as
correct for such installations.

Microsoft detects computers by a hardware fingerprint that takes into
account all the major hardware components, same as it does when a
Windows license is activated on a computer.

In your case, the entire hardware has changed, except for the disk,
so the computer's "fingerprint" has changed and no longer fits that
of the old computer.